# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have simple Spring 4 WebMVC app (Java-config), and I want to add JPA.
But when I try to run app (as deloyed on Tomcat) I get:
What can be a source of error?

> Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.demo.webtemplate.db.repository.CustSysRepository
>   org.demo.webtemplate.controllers.IndexController.repository; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'custSysRepository': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#f4da8a0' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#f4da8a0': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined**

**Initializer:**

```
package org.demo.webtemplate;

...

public class SpringWebMvcInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer  {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Config.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

**Config:**

```
package org.demo.webtemplate;

...

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("pl.bzwbk.webtemplate")
@EnableJpaRepositories("pl.bzwbk.webtemplate.db.repository")
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package org.demo.webtemplate.controllers;

...

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    CustSysRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        List<CustSys> clients = repository.findByFullName("SOME NAME");

        return "index"+clients .size();
    }

}
```

**Repository:**

```
package org.demo.webtemplate.db.repository;

...

public interface CustSysRepository extends JpaRepository<CustSys, Long> {

    List<CustSys> findByFullName(String fullName);
}
```

**Entity:**

```
package org.demo.webtemplate.db.entity;

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUST_SYS")
public class CustSys implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String fullName;
    ...
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    ...
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.pass=
```

Comment: No, that's not the same. In case in that link problem was because he change name of entityManagerFactory to emf, and he use XML config, not Java-Config.

Comment: where have you defined entityManagerFactory?

Answer (score 13):

You're missing completly DB configuration in your `Config` class.

Try this for example:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager() {
    return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("package.where.your.entites.like.CustSys.are.stored");
    return em;
}
```

Comment: It's in application.properties.

Comment: Only DB properties are in application.properties file. You need to define Spring beans as I suggested. Just look at your exception: Spring cannot find entity manager factory bean; now look at my answer: I defined data source, entity manager and entity manager factory beans...

Comment: Hi @rikica ,

Thanks for your answer, it helped me to solve this error. But now I get the following error.

"No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either".

Can you please help?

Comment: can you please open new question? it's very hard to help without any additional info. plus, this question is pretty old one...

Comment: @Son did you find the solution ?  what is the purpose of application.properties file if i do like Rikica said ?

Answer (score 1):

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856266/how-to-make-instance-of-crudrepository-interface-during-testing-in-spring/29622382#29622382) I posted a full example how to unit test a spring controller which needs an autowired JpaRepository.